# Support Emoji icons in TFS / Azure devops

Tags: tfs, emoji

Well, recently i stared working with TFS after many years using bitbucket. I find it hard to comment on code without any useful icons
i used once, like: "thumbs up", "+1" and others.

The version i'm using is: 15.112

I tried searching if TFS has any support for emojis, couldn't find anything about it.
Know it isn't really a pure "coding" question but anyway, please assist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting from TFS 2015 it can support emoji's,You can insert an emoji in **pull request comments and wiki pages**

[As per this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts#emoji)

E.g,

For the below command

```
:smile:
:angry:
```

it will gives you the output like

[image]

You can find the full list of supported emojis [here](https://www.webfx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/)

---

*Some other Updates Just for Information*

As per the [AzureDevOps Spring 143 update](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/new-advanced-text-editor-on-the-work-item-form-in-azure-devops/) there are some now cool features like

•   Code snippets
•   Emojis
•   Resizing images

**Old Text Editor**

[image]
<sub>(source: [windows.net](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2018/11/old2.png))</sub>

**New Text Editor**

[image]
<sub>(source: [windows.net](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2018/11/new.png))</sub>